# Router link in vuetable?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vue-tables-2

I use vuetable 2 in the project. In this table I take data from json. It is necessary to do, for example:
There is a column to Order, in it information ORD1231 ** and so on. When you click on one of the cells, the order goes to another page with a dynamic id. Actually a question, how in vuetable to push router-link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`__slot`](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-tutorial/wiki/lesson-11#__slotname--v120) special field to user router-links.

Inside your `<vuetable>`, use `<template slot=()>`

```
<vuetable ref="vuetable" :fields="fields">
    <template slot="code" slot-scope="props">
        <router-link :to="props.rowData.code"> 
            {{ props.rowData.code }}
        </router-link>
    </template>
</vuetable>
```

and in your script

```
data() {
  return {
    fields: {
      {
        name: '__slot:code'
        title: 'Your Title'
      }
    }
   }
}
```

You can access your data with `props.rowData` and `props.rowIndex` attributes.